# Cannot find module 'NativeAnimatedHelper' when using Jest mock

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-navigation

I have been trying to setup `react-navigation` in my new React Native app. While I have the code/screens working, Jest is causing me issues after adding in the library by following the [v4 docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html).

I installed `react-navigation`, `react-native-reanimated`, `react-native-gesture-handler`, and `react-native-screens@^1.0.0-alpha.23`. I then went into the `ios` folder and ran `pod install`. Because I am on v0.61 of React Native, they should have been autolinked.

When I run the default Jest test, I get an error like:

```
  ✓ renders correctly (106ms)

  console.warn node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/NativeAnimatedHelper.js:270
    Animated: `useNativeDriver` is not supported because the native animated module is missing. Falling back to JS-based animation. To resolve this, add `RCTAnimation` module to this app, or remove `useNativeDriver`. More info: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11094#issuecomment-263240420
```

I searched for this error, and most of the suggested answers were to put this in my test file:

```
jest.mock('NativeAnimatedHelper');
```

However, when I tried doing so, Jest complaing with an error like so:

```
 FAIL  __tests__/App-test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'NativeAnimatedHelper' from 'App-test.tsx'

       6 | import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'
       7 |
    >  8 | jest.mock('NativeAnimatedHelper')
         | ^
       9 |
      10 | it('renders correctly', () => {
      11 |   renderer.create(<App />)

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:259:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/App-test.tsx:8:1)
```

I've been trying various things for awhile now, any help/suggestions would be appreciated!

---

Versions:

```
Node: 10.16.1
npm: 6.11.3
"react": "^16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.1",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.4.1",
"react-native-reanimated": "^1.3.0",
"react-native-screens": "^1.0.0-alpha.23",
"react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
"react-navigation-stack": "^1.9.3",

"babel-jest": "^24.1.0"
"jest": "^24.1.0"
"react-test-renderer": "^16.9.0"
```

Jest config:

```
{
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup.js"
    ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*))"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**Current way of fixing this issue**

*Updated May 18, 2021*

It looks like the location of `NativeAnimatedHelper` has moved in a more recent version of React Native.

Change

`jest.mock('NativeAnimatedHelper');`

To

`jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/Animated/NativeAnimatedHelper');`

---

**Previous way of fixing this issue**

Change

`jest.mock('NativeAnimatedHelper');`

To

`jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/NativeAnimatedHelper');`

Comment: It worked, thanks! Do you know why `jest.mock('NativeAnimatedHelper');` seems to work for most people and why doing the long path was necessary here?

Comment: @saadq I guess it start happening recently, maybe in some new update

Comment: I did not took a deep look into it, but faced the same issue today, and tried mocking the full component's path and it worked

Comment: Got it. Thanks again!

Comment: @JoãoGusmão I didn't find `jest.mock('NativeAnimatedHelper');` in my package.json, so how can I put it in "jest" dictionary?

Comment: @SAMIRRATHOD it is not in package.json, you can find in your node_modules.

Answer (score 10):

With RN 64, it should be `jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/Animated/NativeAnimatedHelper');`

Comment: This works for me. I hit this issue after upgrading react-native to 0.64

Answer (score 8):

**React Native v0.64.0**

The **src** folder was removed from **Animated**

You need to remove **src** from the mock path:

```
Before:
jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/NativeAnimatedHelper');

After:
jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/Animated/NativeAnimatedHelper');
```

Answer (score 5):

Though the accepted answer seems to be working for people and is one of the recommended approaches, it didn't work for me. Plus it is not ideal, as the path could change in the next version.

I was able to properly mock all individual react-native modules following the implementation mentioned in this [blog post](https://altany.github.io/react-native/0.61/jest/mocking/upgrade/2020/01/25/mocking-react-native-0.61-modules-with-jest.html).

Practically, I had to mock the react-native interface by adding a `react-native.js` file inside `test/__mocks` and export the mocked module as:

```
import * as ReactNative from "react-native";

export const Image = "NativeAnimatedHelper";


export default Object.setPrototypeOf(
  {
    NativeAnimatedHelper
  },
  ReactNative
);
```

You can add as many exports as needed in your tests.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to do it every time I used `NativeAnimatedHelper` so instead I have added the mock to `jestSetup.js` file.

```
// test/jestSetup.js
jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/NativeAnimatedHelper');
```

and this file should be included from `jest.config.js` file

```
module.exports = {
  setupFiles: [
    '<rootDir>/tests/jestSetup.js',
  ],
};
```